# Trying to mass-create AD users with a script and add them to a group listed in a CSV file. Not sure what I'm missing

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script for adding and grouping members from info in a CSV. I've done this before on a smaller scale, using a similar method, and it has worked for me. This time, however, it's throwing up a very non-specific error and I'm not sure how to continue.

```
$userlist = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\olygearusers.csv
$surname = $userlist.surname
$passwds = $userlist.accountpassword
$enabled = $userlist.enabled
$givennames = $userlist.givenname
$paths = $userlist.path
$city = $userlist.city
$addresses = $userlist.street
$phones = $userlist.phone
$group = $userlist.group

ForEach($givennames in $userlist){
    if ($city -eq "calgary")
        {new-aduser -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $passwds -asplaintext -force) `
        -Enabled:([bool]([int]$Enabled )) `
        -GivenName $givennames `
        -surName $surname `
        -Name "'$givenname' '$surname'" `
        -path $paths `
        -SamAccountName "'$givennames'.'$surname'.'C'" `
        -UserPrincipalName "'$givennames'.'$surname'.'C'.'@olygear.ca'" `
        -streetaddress $addresses `
        -homephone $phones `
        -city $city `
        -HomeDirectory '\\calgary3\homefolders\%username%' `
        -HomeDrive 'S' `
        -PassThru | Add-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members $_.samaccountname}
    else
        {...}
}

Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
At line:14 char:10
+         {new-aduser -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $passwds ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Again, I've used this method before (albeit much simpler and not trying to add group membership during the process) but I'm not sure how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to move your variable assignments from the top of the script to be inside of the foreach loop because you want them to change at every iteration. The only thing that should remain outside of the loop there is the `$userlist` assignment, but I would rename it to something else like `$users`. Then you can change the foreach loop to `foreach ($userlist in $users) {` and preserve your current variable assighnment syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just rearranging the elements of your code, you can accomplish what you want:

```
$userlist = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\olygearusers.csv
ForEach($user in $userlist){
    $surname = $user.surname
    $passwds = $user.accountpassword
    $enabled = $user.enabled
    $givennames = $user.givenname
    $paths = $user.path
    $city = $user.city
    $addresses = $user.street
    $phones = $user.phone
    $group = $user.group
    if ($city -eq "calgary")
    {
    $NewUser = @{
      AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwds -asplaintext -force
      Enabled = [bool][int]$enabled
      GivenName = $givennames
      surName = $surname
      Name = "$givenname $surname"
      Path = $paths
      SamAccountName = "$givennames.$surname.C"
      UserPrincipalName = "$givennames.$surname.C.@olygear.ca"
      streetaddress = $addresses
      homephone = $phones
      city = $city
      HomeDirectory = '\\calgary3\homefolders\%username%'
      HomeDrive = 'S'
    }
    New-ADUser @NewUser
    Add-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members $samaccountname
    }
    else
        {...}
}
```

Your code currently assigns all of your variables only once. In each assignment, you are creating an array of values. When you run your foreach loop, you are using the same array values for each iteration. Many of those parameters cannot accept an array and therefore throw errors. Using the current object (`$user`) each iteration of the foreach loop, you avoid this problem.

Comment: Could I persuade you to rather use splatting the parameters instead of using the line-continuation backticks? Splatting makes the code so much better readable IMO while backticks are easy to overlook. Just a thought.

Comment: @Theo updates have been made. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi! thank you for replying, but when I run this, I get a different error code.

`Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or 
empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:29 char:81
+ ... Thru | Add-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members $_.samaccountname}
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manageme 
   nt.Commands.AddADGroupMember`

Comment: @LeviFM, that error should be fixed now. I've removed the pipe into `add-adgroupmember` cmdlet.